# Getting package versions on upgrade of apk

Tags: android, version, upgrade

I have a reciever that is supposed to get notified on upgrade of packages. Its filter is defined thus in the manifest:

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
```

In the reciever, in onRecieve() I do get version of package I am upgrading to, but I could not figure out how to get the version I am upgrading from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the version of the application:

```
this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve the problem. Package name does not contain the version.